# Indo-European cognates

Tags: discussion

Where can I discuss the prehistoric relation between Russian and English.  For example Z might be related to our G in zelyoni and zemlya (ge-ometry).  The only clue my teacher ever mentioned was that khleb is related to "loaf." Maybe this is discussed in a different Stack Exchange site?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/297524

Comment: хлеб is a germanic borrowing btw

Answer (score 2):

That probably goes here https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

I think that this kind of questions can be discussed on https://rus.stackexchange.com/ but the text of your question should be written in Russian (you will get the answers also in Russian).